# Custom section numbering (letters and numbers)

Tags: enumerate, letters, section-titles

Can I have something like that ?

```
1. section one
  1.1 subsection one
  1.2 subsction two

2. section two
  2.1 subsection two

    A. title
       1) subtitle A.1
       2) subtitle A.2

    B. title
       1) subtitle B.1
           a) subsubtitle B.1.a
           b) subsubtitle B.1.b
       2) subtitle B.2

    C. title
    .
    .
    .
    .
    etc

          2.1.1 subsubsection two one
          2.1.2 subsubsection two two
          2.1.3 subsubsection two three
          2.1.4 subsubsection two four
```

The idea is to introduce a title/section that is enumerated with a **letter** or eventually somthing else but without changing the sections structure.  So this enumerating can appear the same in **toc**.

Answer (score 2):

You could add new section levels with [`titlesec`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec). The following example introduces two new section levels, `\Title` and `\subtitle` (the capital T is there to avoid confusion with the `\title` command), which are below `\subsection` and above `\subsubsection`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleclass{\Title}{straight}[\subsection]
\titleclass{\subtitle}{straight}[\Title]
\newcounter{Title}
\newcounter{subtitle}
\renewcommand*{\theTitle}{\Alph{Title}}
\renewcommand*{\thesubtitle}{\arabic{subtitle})}
\titleformat{\Title}{\bfseries\large}{\theTitle}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subtitle}{\bfseries}{\thesubtitle}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\Title}{1.5em}{6pt}{6pt}
\titlespacing*{\subtitle}{3em}{6pt}{6pt}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}

\begin{document}

\section{Section one}
\subsection{Subsection one}
\subsection{Subsection two}

\section{Section two}
\subsection{Subsection one}
\Title{Title}
\subtitle{Subtitle A.1}
\subtitle{Subtitle A.2}

\subsubsection{Subsubsection one}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection two}
\end{document}
```

The output is the following.

[image]

The general formatting of the new section levels can be changed with `\titleformat` and `\titlespacing`, and the numbering can be changed with the `\theTitle` and `\thesubtitle` commands. With this example, the new section levels will appear in ToC, but the formatting should be manually handled, for example with `titletoc`.